# lsf : getting "LSF is down. Please wait " message while running badmin mbdrestart

Tags: lsf

I have installed a new IBM Spectrum LSF Community Edition 10.1.0.6

when i run :

```
badmin mbdrestart
```

i am getting the below output:

LSF is down. Please wait

Note:

running  the below commands was successful:

lsadmin limstartup

lsadmin resstartup

badmin hstartup

lsadmin limrestart all

Comment: Any success? Im having the same problem, wasted already over 10 hours fiddling around and reinstalling and no success